# Australian passport processing time overseas

Tags: passports, canada, australian-citizens, short-notice, local-knowledge

I went into the consulate the other day to apply for the renewal of my Australian passport as I was born there and haven't renewed it in the past year. I had all the documents in order and the application was approved. The Australian Passports Office website says that it only takes ten days to get a passport but they said at the consulate that it would take six weeks.

Are there any other Aussies who could share with me their experience regarding passport waiting time?

Note: I live in Canada, the regional passport processing centre for Australia is in Washington.

Comment: Should be in expat.se

Comment: @Vagish off topic? I've had to renew my NZ passport overseas while travelling as well. Doesn't mean you're an expat. Indeed I have to do it again this month, although this time I'm technically an expat as well as a traveller, the process doesn't care what my status is.

Comment: (I agree it _could_ be on expats, but it's not off topic on travel)

Comment: He isn't traveling. That is the passport office for where he lives. The expat.se would know better than the travel.se...

Comment: Still the exact same problem can face a traveller under certain circumstances. I think it's on topic on either/both sites as per [the Pee-Wee Herman Rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).

Comment: I just submitted my passport renewal right here in Sydney and the form and the Post Office told me it takes *three weeks*. A few days later I rang them and asked if it will be quicker to pick it up in person. The answer was yes but it's still going to exactly *two weeks* from when I lodged the application to the day I can pick it up.

Comment: Also I had to get a new Aussie passport once while I was in Vancouver and was shocked that it took only about *three days*! That was however around 1996/1998 (before biometric passports, before 9/11 caused many rules and processes to be changed). It was also an emergency passport (six months validity) rather than a full renewed passport.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliantly, they're not clear on the [embassy website for Aussies in Canada.](http://www.canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/consular.html)  However, after some searching it comes down to two options.

1. The express service - priority processing fee applies, means that your urgent/emergency application can be [processed and ready for collection or dispatch](http://www.canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/090321_Travel_Doc_Fees.html) within 48 hours.
2. The standard service - where it goes via mail through their center in Washington, DC, most likely, [takes 10 working days from receipt of all valid documents](https://www.passports.gov.au/Web/FAQ.aspx#faq4):

> We are equally committed to prompt processing of passport applications
>   made overseas at any Australian diplomatic or consular mission. In
>   most cases an eligible applicant's full validity passport will be
>   available for collection or despatch from the mission within ten
>   working days of a passport interview if all our requirements are met.
>   It will be issued by one of our passport production centres - London,
>   Washington, or Canberra. You should allow extra time for local mail
>   delivery if you have requested that the passport be mailed to you.

They also point out that if you need it sooner, you should resort to option 1.